# Bootstrap 4.1.1 form-check form-check-inline radio button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to display a radio button as inline option.
In the Bootstrap 4.1.1 docs the example code is:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3 (disabled)</label>
</div>
```

Despite I clone this to my html it does not work and radio button are displayed normal.

My **Html** code is:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'surveys/style.css' %}" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TFM Survey</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="../../assets/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="../../assets/js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <form action="{% url 'surveys:vote' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% if questions %}
        <ul class="list-group">

        {% for question in questions %}
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">{{ question.question_text}}</li>
            {% if question.choice_set.all %}
                {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.choice_text }}">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type some answer..." name="{{ question.id }}"/>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% else %}
            <p>No questions are available.</p>
        {% endif %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Vote" />
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using also the `class="checkbox-inline"` but It doesn't work neither.
I have seen that the `div` tends to use all the width, so I also specify:

```
#radio-div{
 width:auto
}
```

But neither works (I have used the id statement in the radio input).
Does anyone if there is some clear mistake in this implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, Your `<ul>` `<li>` element is invalid. 
This means that inside a  there can only be multiple `<li>` elements.
`<ul>` should only contain `li` elements.

**Your Code sample:** Here, You are put your radio button element outside of `<li>` elements.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">YOUR TEXT CONTENT</li>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
  </div>
</ul>
```

**Corrected Code sample:** You will need to put radio button element code inside `<li>` elements.

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">YOUR TEXT CONTENT
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow `Bootstrap` markup and `classes` to achieve this

- First, You need to add `custom-control` and `custom-radio` classes
  with `form-check-inline`
- Add `custom-control-input` class in `input`
- Add `custom-control-label` class in `label`

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* just to make inline radio, You can remove this if you want */
.custom-control {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check form-check-inline">

  <input class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
  <label class="custom-control-label form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>

</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
  <label class="custom-control-label form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
</div>


<div class="custom-control custom-radio form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="custom-control-input form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
  <label class="custom-control-label form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3 (disabled)</label>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You added bootstrap.js in a link tag, please change it to as

```
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

And alse note that jquery must be required first, like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

If the issue still exists, 
add class `radio-inline` instead of `form-check form-check-inline`, like this

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <div class="radio-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio3" value="option3" disabled>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio3">3 (disabled)</label>
    </div>
```