# Place radio and text inline

Tags: css, inline

I want this result like [Bootstrap 5 - Place Radio Buttons Inline and a Radio Input Group next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67594828/bootstrap-5-place-radio-buttons-inline-and-a-radio-input-group-next-to-each-ot)
But he uses bootstrap 5, I use bootstrap 3.3.7 so it does not work.

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' />
    <label class='form-check-label'>Y</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
    <input class='form-check-input' type='radio' />
    <label class='form-check-label text-nowrap'>N</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <label>XXX</label><input type='text' />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank Gerard. But it's different from my thought.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815278/bootstrap-4-1-1-form-check-form-check-inline-radio-button

This requires few modifications in the code though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional CSS to modify the alignment.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2">
    <input type='radio' />
    <label>Y</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-2">
    <input type='radio' />
    <label>N</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <label>XXX</label><input type='text' />
  </div>
</div>
```